# Error building hyperledger fabric : “bzip2 data Creating Error” in goshim.tar.bz2

Tags: makefile, linux-kernel, hyperledger-fabric, raspberry-pi3, opensuse

### Preconditions

- Fabric 1.4
- I have openSUSE on Raspbery Pi3+

### Details of the Error

I ran the following command.

```
# make docker
```

- Failed to create `goshim.tar.bz2` error occurred and I can't make commond.

  ```
  Removing intermediate container fb7423fe5cf7
   ---> 24c6fdada18f
  Successfully built 24c6fdada18f
  Successfully tagged hyperledger/fabric-orderer:latest
  docker tag hyperledger/fabric-orderer hyperledger/fabric-orderer:arm64-1.4.1-snapshot-e91c57c5f
  docker tag hyperledger/fabric-orderer hyperledger/fabric-orderer:arm64-latest
  Creating .build/goshim.tar.bz2
  make: execvp: /bin/sh: Argument list too long
  make: *** [Makefile:315: .build/goshim.tar.bz2] Error 127
  ```
- Makefile

  ```
  $(BUILD_DIR)/goshim.tar.bz2: $(GOSHIM_DEPS)
          @echo "Creating $@"
          @tar -jhc -C $(GOPATH)/src $(patsubst $(GOPATH)/src/%,%,$(GOSHIM_DEPS)) > $@
  ```

Is there a way to avoid this phenomenon?

Answer (score 1):

> make: execvp: /bin/sh: Argument list too long

This is probably caused by the source file list produced by `GOSHIM_DEPS`, that is too long for paremeters to `sh`,  which is implicitly executed.

Try this: replace `@tar` line with 
    `@./scripts/goListFiles.sh $(PKGNAME)/core/chaincode/shim | sed “s!$(GOPATH)/src/!!g” |xargs tar -jhc -C $(GOPATH)/src > $@`

I don’t have an environment identical as yours so the above code may have errors, but the basic idea could be applied.

**EDIT**: That said, there would still be some chances that the error may remain. `GOSHIM_DEPS` itself is defined using `$()` syntax and is under the upper limit of length of sh parameter.